# android - HttpGet trying to run php script

Tags: php, android, http, httpclient

I'm trying to run a php script from my web server But for some reason the request keeps failing and going to the catch. Not sure what else I need to add to simply send a request to the server

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public void phpRequest()
    {
         HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
         final String url = "http://192.168.1.103/lock.php";

         try
         {
             client.execute(new HttpGet(url));
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
         }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn_lock = (Button)findViewById(R.id.lock);
        Button btn_sleep = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sleep);
        Button btn_shutdown = (Button)findViewById(R.id.shutdown);

        btn_lock.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                phpRequest();
            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I have already added INTERNET permission to my AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: A stack trace (`Log.e("MyActivityTag", "It failed!", e)` will print one, as will throwing a RuntimeException wrapping the Exception) would help diagnose this.  But my guess is that it's because you're trying to do blocking IO on the UI thread, which is a no-no in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem most likely is that you are calling the phpRequest method from the OnClickListener which runs on the UI thread. So you could simply start a new thread in the OnClickListener and start it like this:

```
new Thread() {
    public void run(){
        phpRequest();
    }
}.start();
```